# Parse JSON File Starting with Curly Brace

Tags: json, xcode, parsing, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a set of data in my `database` and I am unable to parse it through `xcode`. As the `JSON` file starts with a curly brace, I am constantly getting nil when i try to print the value upon parsing.

I am currently using `XAMPP` and I have done up the required `PHP` files and I have also tested that my `database` is working using `INSOMNIA`. However, I am unfamiliar on the parsing prior to data retrieval.

```
struct Coordinate: Codable {

    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let latitude: Float
    let longitude: Float
    let address: String

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/callCenter/v2/getCoordinates.php")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
{ (data, _, _) in

    if let data = data {

        let coordinates = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Coordinate].self, from: data)

        print(coordinates)
        }

        } .resume()
    }
}
```

So upon running of program, I am printing NILs repeatedly. I highly its due to my first few lines of struct code. I have managed to print the size of the `json` file through this program as well.

Please do help me. Have been stuck for quite a few days.

Comment: I apologise with my formatting :/

Comment: You can edit and fix it...

Comment: alright im done!